# Why does defining log4j object using only XML elements not work?

Tags: java, xml, configuration, log4j

Log4j 2.13.1

Java 1.8.192

I'm looking at the log4j2 documentation on XML configuration and I'm obvously missing something because what I think the documentation is telling me does not appear to be valid.  The first section of https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#XML gives something similar to that shown below as an example of using XML elements instead of XML attributes to define the properties of Log4j object.  If you try this it causes a ExceptionInInitializerError.  Is the documentation wrong, or have I misunderstood it?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Configuration>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who stumbles apon this issue, I've found the answer.  There was a bug in 2.13.1 (and I think 2.13.0 as I tried that version too.)  It has been fixed in 2.13.3 and didn't exist in 2.12.0.

Moral: avoid 2.13.1 and live you life happier.